# Does Serena Dimensions have support for Maven Plugins or Ant Tasks?

Tags: maven-2, ant, build-automation, dimensions

There is a lot of contradicting statements regarding whether ANT or Maven support Dimensions (NOT PVCS). Does anyone with real hands on experience know if there exists a reliable, production grade/ready plugin or task for Dimensions? I basically just need to be able to use Maven (preferably) or Ant to grab some revision in Dimensions and build from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, Dimensions is [not supported](http://maven.apache.org/scm/scms-overview.html) by the SCM plugin. Maybe there is an Ant Task that you could call from AntRun but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I did see that wiki. Do you think it is accurate? Also, it seems hudson-CI does support Dimensions CM. What I don't get is, how does Hudson-CI build a java/j2ee project, one would think it certainly isn't use maven/ant with regards to this plugin: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Dimensions+Plugin

Comment: @Zombies Yes, I think the wiki is accurate, the Maven SCM plugin doesn't support Dimensions CM. And I'm not sure to understand your question about Hudson and its Dimensions plugin (interacting with a VCS and building are two different things).

Comment: I am under the impression that Hudson CI will build an EAR file by grabbing a revision from Dimensions. I was wondering what it used to build.

Comment: @Zombies It does grab a revision from Dimensions but this doesn't prevent the build to be done by Maven.

Answer (score 1):

im developing this, http://code.google.com/p/mvn-scm-plugin-dimensions/ i hope in a few days i have support for checkout, checkin, tag, status, update and maybe changelog.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I use an Ant task like this to pull the latest source for my project:

```
<target name="get_source" description='execute Serena Dimensions and get latest code.'>
    <exec executable="DMCLI">
        <arg value="-cmd"/>
        <!-- EOL=UNCHANGED is important for FWI command to avoid corrupting image files -->
        <arg value="&quot;FWI MYPROJ:MAIN /EOL=UNCHANGED /USER_DIRECTORY=\&quot;${project.dir}&quot;&quot;"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```